# OData as API-Gateway in MicroService architect

Tags: odata, microservices, api-gateway

I want to use OData as API-Gateway. Is it possible? Is there any example of OData that get rest request and use another service instead of entity framework provider?

I have some service that provide data and my services are using deferent type of databases SQL and NO-SQL. I want to use OData as a service provider of my architecture which my clients only see one endpoint and send OData requests then I can manage which service must response the request.

I searched and found there is some way to create custom provider for OData. Is there a way to use OData as API-Gateway?